# spring test not populating database configuration from application.properties

Tags: jdbc, spring-boot, spring-test

In my spring boot application, I have the following class that calls a stored procedure

```
public class FmTrfUtil {
    static int returnVal;

    public static int insertFmTrfs(List<String> trfs, String source) {
        EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RIStore_FM").createEntityManager();
        Session session = em.unwrap( Session.class );
        final String[] trfArray = trfs.toArray(new String[trfs.size()]);
        final String src = source;

        session.doWork( new Work(){
            public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                CallableStatement stmt = null;        
                OracleConnection oraCon = conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
                Array array = oraCon.createARRAY("VARCHAR2_TAB_T", trfArray);
                stmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = call FM_TRF_UTIL.process_fm_trf(?,?)}");
                stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
                stmt.setArray(2, array);
                stmt.setString(3, src);
                stmt.execute();
                returnVal = stmt.getInt(1);
            }
        });
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

Now I would like to run integration test on this class using spring test following example in [Integration Testing a Spring Boot Application](https://www.jayway.com/2014/07/04/integration-testing-a-spring-boot-application/).

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = RistoreWebApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class FmTrfUtilTest {

    static EntityManagerFactory factory = null;
    static EntityManager manager = null;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<String> trfs = new ArrayList<String>();
        trfs.add("TRF000001");
        trfs.add("TRF000002");
        int ret = FmTrfUtil.insertFmTrfs(trfs, "SARC");
        assertTrue(ret > 0);
    }
}
```

Here `RistoreWebApplication` is the name of the main app class which is the entry point of the api. According to that web page, "The `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` annotation will trigger logic for reading Spring Boot specific configurations, properties, and so on." My understanding is this will load database connection information in my application.properties as well:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://xxx:389/risdev3, cn=OracleContext,dc=yyy,dc=com
spring.datasource.username=rowner
spring.datasource.password=rowner987
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

However, when I run this test, I got `UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections`. How exactly do I load the db connection config running the test? I am using spring boot 1.3

**EDIT**
since application.properties lives in src/main/resources while my test classes are in src/test/java, I figured I'd have another property file under `src/test/resources` based on the answer to [Spring jUnit Testing properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974432/spring-junit-testing-properties-file). So I did that and added annotation `@PropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")` in my test class, but still getting the same error. Is there a way to know whether the property file is being read and/or what is the current classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your test class like below:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = RistoreWebApplication.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

Please refer below:

[Spring boot, read yml properties via integration test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390085/spring-boot-read-yml-properties-via-integration-test-case)

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs.old/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/initializer/ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.html

**EDIT: with respect to below comment.**

Access your datastore via your Repository.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html

```
@Autowired
YourRepository repository;
repository.save(Arrays.asList("value_1", "value_2", "value_3"));
```

Comment: I added the `initializers` and still does not work. Tried to print out some property by `System.getProperty` and it is null. Now I start to wonder if the class is correct for `SpringApplicationConfiguration`. Should I be using the main app class which is the entry point of the whole project or something else?

Comment: I am able to get properties in test class now. However, when I still got `The application must supply JDBC connections` error when executing the `insertFmTrfs` method. Error is thrown at `session.doWork` line to be exact. While the properties are not picked up in this method?

Comment: That's correct, you're not supposed to create the connection. The DB connection object will be supplied by the Springboot during runtime and that's the whole purpose.

Answer (score 2):

`@PropertySource` is for use on an `@Configuration` class, not on a test class.

On your test class, you should instead use `@TestPropertySource`.